# Trigger view function with bootstrap button

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7

I don't really get how to make a button click trigger my view function... I already googled, but nothing really helps me understand...
In my html, I have:

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="{% url "device-detail" device.pk %}" name = 'rotateleft'>Rotate Left</a>
```

And in my views.py:

```
class DeviceDetail(DetailView):
    ....
   def rotate_left(request, self):
     if request.GET.get('rotateleft') == 'rotateleft':
        print 'TEST!!!!'
        self.image.open()
        self.image.rotate(-90)
        self.image.save()
```

If I click the button, the page seems to be reloaded as planned, but as 'TEST' is not printed (and the image is not rotated, but it might be that the code that is supposed to rotate it doesn't work yet, I wanted to call the function to see if it works), I'm guessing that this function is never called.

I am relatively new to Django and very new to the web interface side of Django, so help would be really appreciated!

Comment: use single qoute `"{% url 'device-detail' device.pk %}"` to define url name.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing a few things here. Clicking the link will "refresh" the `DeviceDetail` page as you noticed. Adding a `name` attribute on your HTML link won't however affect the request made to the server.

Based on what you are trying to accomplish it seems you should use a simple view function and perhaps read in a a GET parameter for deciding which way to rotate your image. Note that the parameters you pass to your view needs to be within the link URL, like:

href="{% url "device-detail" device.pk %}?rotate=right"

Comment: So i would just append something like ?rotate=right to my url and do `if '?rotate=right'` in request.GET and that would trigger the view function?

Comment: Did that, it still doesn't return `TEST~ and also the url doesn't really look good anymore... :/  Isn't there any way to press a button and thus trigger the function?

Comment: As I tried pointing out there's nothing in your code that even triggers your `rotate_left` function. What I meant was that you would replace your class-based `DetailView` with a simple view. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/ for documentation.

In that view you can check the GET parameter using something like:

if request.GET.get('rotate') == 'left':

The parameter will as you noticed show up in the URL. This will always be the case unless you send the request using a POST request. 

A better approach would perhaps be using ajax for the request.